# Linked Lists Java Lietner Flashcard

Tags: java, unix

I need to create a class called box that uses a linked list to store flashcards that contain two strings as input.

```
public class FlashCard {

    public static String challenge;
    public static  String response;

    public FlashCard(String front, String back)
    {   
        double a = Math.random();
        if(a > 0.5) challenge = front;
        else challenge = back;

        if(a < 0.5) response = front;
        else response = back;
    }

    private static String getChallenge()
    {
        return challenge;
    }

    private static String getResponse(String in)
    {
        return response;
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        FlashCard card = new FlashCard("Ryan Hardin", "Student at UAB");
        System.out.print(challenge);
    }

}
```

This is my box class that is using a linked list as an instance variable to store the cards but keep getting error messages.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Box {

private LinkedList<FlashCard> data;

public Box() {
    this.data = new LinkedList<FlashCard>();

}

public Box addCard(FlashCard r) {
    Box one = this;
    one.data = data.add(0,r);

    return one;
}
```

Comment: Is there a question in there? I'm not sure what you want here.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would go about actually adding elements to the box I have tried but it does not work. I can't store elements inside the box object. I wanted to know why.

Comment: You haven't provided any methods on Box to add instances. If you want to do something to a Box (like add things to it, get things out of it, count the things in it, etc.), you'll need to add methods that accomplish those things to the Box class.

Answer (score 0):

- Put the linked list outside the constructor as an instance variable of Box class - lets call it boxList
- In your main method of Box do boxList.add(new FlashCard())

Comment: If I do that then not using the class, I'm just adding flashcards to the linked lists.

Comment: Add a getter to get the whole Flashcard list from Box. Since your flashcard doesn't have a unique field you need to get the whole list and iterate through it